# How can i automatically post on the user wall Facebook graph

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi how can i simply post something to the users wall when hes connected ?

I tried this :

```
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
          <script  type="text/javascript"> 

            FB.init({
              appId      : '35455XXXX46207', // App ID
              status     : true, // check login status
              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });


var publish = {
  method: 'feed',
  message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
  name: 'Connect',
  caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
  description: (
      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
  ),
  link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/',
  picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  actions: [
    { name: 'fbrell', link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/' }
  ],
  user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about RELL'
};

FB.ui(publish, Log.info.bind('feed callback'));
</script>
```

This open a facebook popup, but i want to do this directly with some code .. (like spotify do)

What is the issue ? (Ive got the ext_perms for that)

Thanks

Comment: "Can't make this work too" is not an issue description. You want us to make your work for you?

Comment: No, i just cant find any way to post on the users wall.. :( I just want some help to start with

Comment: FB is undefined in my case dunno why :(

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: I updated my post ive got a news problem. Thanks

Comment: "new popup open with a facebook error inside" --- and now we need to guess what exact error? We don't see your monitor. People, why do you always try to ask a question in a way not possible to answer?

Comment: I updated the post again

Comment: Example: http://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/feed

Comment: got still the same error with that code, is it possible to make this with php ?

Comment: @Anthony: why don't you just take **working** example and then iteratively step by step change it to what you need?

Comment: It works now but i want to make this automatically with some code.. Is it possible ? (eg spotify)

Comment: No ideas to post directly without showing a popup ?

Answer (score 0):

Spotify uses the Open Graph.

Joe Bloggs {action}'d an {object} on {app}

so Joe Bloggs {'listened to'} a {'song name and title'} on {'Spotify'}

you can configure what these are, and you need to get those permissions when accepting the app.

Go to your app in FB developers > App > Edit App > Open Graph.

That's how you can do it. As for an automatic share, I am unsure, I'm looking for it myself, but suspect it's not doable.  Imagine the ability for abuse.  But it sounds like open Graph will do what you want.